# Issue in showing multiple data in the row of each column of a listview

Tags: android, android-layout

Guys i have tried different ways to show the data.I tried grouping multiple textview in linearlayout but its hiding other columns data.

My scenario is i have a item number,style number in a single column,uptil now i am able to show only item number ,just below i want to show style number like this i have few more columns where i have to show data on below the other has shown in image.

Following is my item display layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="TextView" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Following is my listview layout

```
 <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
           />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Comment" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Comment goes here"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAcc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Accept" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRej"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:text="Reject" />


</LinearLayout>
```

The image shows what exactly is required.
[image]

Comment: @Dhaval Gondaliya Please check this out,the other post did not worked out

Comment: @Erfan Mowlaei check this out

Comment: @codeMagic i am stuck here,please see this

Answer (score 0):

So you want header for a List view i.e. titles of each column

You can do this in two ways.
1.The Data that you pass to the array adapter has to have the titles as 0th position element,that is one way but changing header color is bit complex

2.This is the proper way is using getviewtype override method of Listview you can organize the layout and UI

Comment: i dont need header i need to show multiple data in same same row of each column,see image

Comment: just add one more textview row below and use that

Answer (score 0):

I think u could use grid view instead of list view to show your data.

Comment: first i need to try with this,i know there is some issue with layout headers because of which i am failing to do

Comment: can u elaborate ur issue

Comment: I need to show two or more data in each row of the column has shown in image,but for now i m able to display only item number.see the image it will be clear

Comment: no ,i am thinking this should work out,i tried grouping the textviews in linearlayout but in vain.if this wont then i will try out other ways